# Vim conceal feature is applied to active line

Tags: vim, latex, macvim, vim-plugins

I am using MacVim with the [vim-latex](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net) plugin. There is a `conceal` feature turned on by default that converts LaTeX symbols to unicode in vim itself so the source is easier to read. I think this is supposed to turn off on the active line (under the cursor) but this isn't happening, meaning I can't edit the code in parts.

Is there a way to make the conceal feature only apply for inactive lines? Otherwise, how do I turn it off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:set concealcursor=""` turns conceal off on the active line in all modes.

```
:h concealcursor
```

Comment: You don't need the `""`, and that's the built-in default value, anyway. If you're just into _editing_ the concealed chars, `nc` is a good value.

Comment: Thanks, for some reason it wasn't set to empty (maybe vim-latex or another plugin was screwing it up).

Answer (score 0):

An useful mapping to toggle conceallevel:

```
nnoremap <Leader>c :let &cole=(&cole == 2) ? 0 : 2 <bar> echo 'conceallevel ' . &cole <CR>
```